# Why isn't the Range.Find method finding the first instance of a string?

Tags: vba, excel

In the range `A1:I1`, the exact string "*ContactName" appears twice - once in `A1` and again in `I1`. [Here is a link to a picture of the range.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvNIq.png)

My code below returns 9 when I expected in to return 1.

Please could someone explain why? I have read Microsoft's documentation but still can't figure it out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx

```
Sub FindCol()
    Dim destinationCol As Integer
    destinationCol = Range("A1:I1").Find("*ContactName").Column
    MsgBox destinationCol
End Sub
```

If I alter the code to start from column I then, as expected, the method loops back around and returns 1 (column A).

```
Sub FindCol()
    Dim destinationCol As Integer
    destinationCol = Range("A1:I1").Find("*ContactName", after:=Cells(1, 9)).Column
    MsgBox destinationCol
End Sub
```

Comment: note that `*` is a wildcard that matches any 0 or more characters so `.Find("~*ContactName")` can be used instead https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/09/29/using-excel-find-replace/#find-replace-wildcards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation that you link to, about the optional parameter `After`:

> The cell after which you want the search to begin. This corresponds to
>   the position of the active cell when a search is done from the user
>   interface. Notice that After must be a single cell in the range.
>   Remember that the search begins after this cell; the specified cell
>   isn't searched until the method wraps back around to this cell. If you
>   do no specify this argument, the search starts after the cell in the
>   upper-left corner of the range.

You didn't provide an `After` hence in this case it defaults to `A1`. Note the part of the documentation which says "the specified cell isn't searched until the method wraps back around to this cell."

If you use:

```
destinationCol = Range("A1:I1").Find("*ContactName", Range("I1")).Column
```

it will work as you intend.

Comment: You picked up a comment in that documentation that I didn't notice.  (I just saw the last sentence.)  I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @YowE3K No need to delete yours, but thanks. Your answer beat mine by about 30 seconds or so. This really is counter-intuitive. I don't know why Microsoft designed it this way.

Comment: (a) I figured there was no reason to have two answers that were almost identical - and yours is that slight bit better - so let's keep the site neat.  (b) If Microsoft's products were intuitive the whole [excel-vba] tag on SO would be redundant, and then I would have 0 reputation!

Answer (score 0):

Better to use a range object and test if the object is found before returning the column (else the code will error).

Also better to fully qualify the `Find` parameters (in this case starting the start after the last cell in the range, ie start after *I1*)

```
Sub FindCol()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set rng1 = Range("A1:I1").Find("*ContactName", [i1], xlFormulas, , xlNext)
    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then MsgBox rng1.Column
End Sub
```